# how to pass clicked item's data with onItemClickListener() to another activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, onitemclicklistener

I have phonebook app which stores new Contacts in sqlite table. I have activities to add and (list)View contacts, and they are working just fine.
Now, I need a Details activity which will show the details of contact cliked in the listView. 
I know that I should use `onItemClickListener()`, but everything that I have tried is not working. Details Activity is containt three TextViews (name, last name, phone).
All I can get is an error :

> *DataProvider cannot be cast to java.lang.String*

If there is another way to do this, please be so kind telling me how.

Here is the DisplayDataActivity.java :

```
public class DisplayDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


ListView listView;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
UserDbHelper userDbHelper;
Cursor cursor;
ListDataAdapter listDataAdapter;


EditText Search_Last;
String search_Last;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_data);



    Search_Last = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchName);

    // This part of the code is from tutorial
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_display);
    listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_layout);
    listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);

    userDbHelper = new UserDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = userDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = userDbHelper.getInformations(sqLiteDatabase);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            String name, lastName, phone;
            name = cursor.getString(0);
            lastName = cursor.getString(1);
            phone = cursor.getString(2);
            DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(name, lastName);
            listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // Opens detailed view when contact is clicked
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



            TextView entryName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.entryNameDetail);
            TextView entryLastName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.entryLastDetail);
            TextView entryPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.entryPhoneDetail);

            String data = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


            String Name = entryName.getText().toString();
            String Last = entryLastName.getText().toString();
            String Phone = entryPhone.getText().toString();

            Intent modify_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailView.class);
            modify_intent.putExtra("Name", Name);
            modify_intent.putExtra("last", Last);
            modify_intent.putExtra("phone", Phone);

            startActivity(modify_intent);


        }
    });



}
```

Here is the DataProvider.java:

```
public class DataProvider {

private String name;
private String lastName;
private String phone;

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public DataProvider(String name, String lastName)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;


}}
```

DetailView.java:

```
public class DetailView extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView entryName, entryLastName, entryPhone;
ImageView entryPhoto;
Cursor cursor;

private DataProvider dataProvider;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_view);




    /* WHEN I RUN THIS PART OF THE CODE, THE NAME TEXTVIEW SHOWS EMPTY
    Bundle data_from_list = getIntent().getExtras();
    String value_in_name = data_from_list.getString("passed key data");
    TextView entryName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.entryNameDetail);
    entryName.setText(value_in_name);
    */

    /* Running this code throws me an error from above */
    Intent modify_intent = getIntent();
    String s1 = modify_intent.getStringExtra("Name");
    String s2 = modify_intent.getStringExtra("Last");
    String s3 = modify_intent.getStringExtra("Phone");

    entryName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.entryNameDetail);
    entryLastName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.entryLastDetail);
    entryPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.entryPhoneDetail);

    entryName.setText(s1);
    entryLastName.setText(s2);
    entryPhone.setText(s3);


    // Adding hardcoded data into TextView for testing purposes
    // WORKING
    //entryName.setText("Test ime");
    //entryLastName.setText("Test PRezime");
    //entryPhone.setText("test telefon");


}}
```

ListDataAdapter.class:

```
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
List list = new ArrayList();

public ListDataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}

static class LayoutHandler
{
    TextView NAME, LASTNAME;

}

@Override
public void add(Object object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
        layoutHandler.NAME = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_user_name);
        layoutHandler.LASTNAME = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_user_last);
        row.setTag(layoutHandler);

    }
    else
    {
        layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();


    }
    DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider) this.getItem(position);
    layoutHandler.NAME.setText(dataProvider.getName());
    layoutHandler.LASTNAME.setText(dataProvider.getLastName());

    return row;


}}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the ListDataAdapter class ?

Comment: First of all, when passing string to a new activity, make sure your key has EXACTLY the same spelling. I see that you wrote "Name","last","phone" in one activity and "Name","Last","Phone" in another

Comment: @aqm , yes of course, I have added it.

Answer (score 1):

```
listDataAdapter.add(dataProvider);
```

I think you must add dataProvider (which is the data you want to add to your list) to the ArrayList and not to your custom Adapter.

Instead you associate the custom adapter to the ArrayList and the ListView for visualization.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need this line?

```
String data = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

You aren't using that variable anywhere and that line is giving you that error (probably).

Also I think you should be using view.findViewById instead of just findViewById inside the onItemClick listener.

Comment: I just  forgot to delete/comment that line from something previous I have tried. It's not working when I delete it, neither when I try using view.findViewById.